# Is it possible to print entered number twice by adding different keywords before and after that number?

Tags: javascript, html

Entered number:

```
1.2.0.0
2.25.0.0
25.3.0.0

<script>
function pad(num, diff) {
return diff > 0 ? pad(num, diff - 1) + 0 : num;
}

function processString(num) {
var tmp = num.replace(/\.+/g, '');
var diff = 4 - tmp.length;
var tmpl = '<key>#{padded}</key>'+'<string>#{padded}</string>';
var padded = diff > 0 ? pad(tmp, diff).split('').join('.') : num;
return tmpl.replace('#{padded}', padded);
}

var button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener('click', processArea);

function processArea() {
var area = document.getElementById('area');
var arr = area.value.split(/\n/);
var header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM   
"file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">\n<plist   
version="1.0">\n<dict>\n<array>\n';
var footer = '\n</array>\n</plist>';
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  arr[i] = processString(arr[i]);
}
area.value = header+arr.join('\r\n')+footer;
}

</script>
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM   
"file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<array>
<key>1.2.0.0</key><string>#{padded}</string>
<key>2.2.5.0</key><string>#{padded}</string>
<key>2.5.3.0</key><string>#{padded}</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM   
"file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<array>
<key>1.2.0.0</key>
<string>1.2.0.0</string>
<key>2.25.0.0</key>
<string>2.25.0.0</string>
<key>25.3.0.0</key>
<string>25.3.0.0</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Can any one help me please, how do i can achieve this output.

I want the entered list must be print twice with different prefix and post-fix as shown in expected output

But i am not able to get such output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace will only change the first occurrence of the string, unfortunately so instead of:

`return tmpl.replace('#{padded}', padded);`

Try using a regexp to replace all occurrences of the string

```
var pattern = '#\{padded\}';
var regEx = new RegExp(pattern , 'g');

return tmpl.replace(regEx, padded);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply

http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/20/

Can you explain me with fiddle please

Comment: I made the change via jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/21/
It is pretty much creating a pattern looking for `#{padded}` and then replacing all occurrences in the string. The `\ ` character is in there to escape out the `{ }` braces.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I did update a few things to match your expected output above: https://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/22/